# How to generate copies in ESC / POS

Tags: php, printing, thermal-printer, epson, escpos

You want to print two copies of a voucher in ESC / POS language, but I can not find the function in the documentation to do it

just as there is a command to cut the paper

```
$ printer-> cut ();
```

just as there is a command to feed the paper

```
$ printer-> feed (3);
```

There is not one that, when I pass a certain parameter, prints a voucher n times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with ESC/POS.  You have to send all data three times if you want three copies.